# Python and psycopg2 multiprocessing performance with large data set

Tags: python, memory, psycopg2

I have a pretty standard multiprocessing script that processes 2 million records in a database table. Before I even finish putting work in the worker_queue, the memory usage balloons over 12GB and crashes. Is there a better way to design this?

```
import math
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import DictCursor
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

from config import DB

connection = psycopg2.connect(DB)
cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=DictCursor)

def worker(worker_queue, progress):
    for row in iter(worker_queue.get, None):
        # Do work
        progress.put(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    total, done = 0, 0

    cursor.execute("SELECT * from table")

    manager = Manager()
    worker_queue = manager.Queue()
    progress = manager.Queue()

    for row in cursor:
        worker_queue.put(row)
        total += 1

    workers = [Process(target=worker, args=(worker_queue, progress)) for i in range(50)]

    for each in workers:
        each.start()

    for i in iter(progress.get, None):
        done += 1

        remaining = total - done

        if remaining == 0:
            print 'Done'
        elif ((remaining % (10 ** int(math.log10(remaining)))) == 0):
            print str(remaining) + ' remaining'
```

Comment: How big your data is? I mean each row. 12Gb over 2mln is 6.2Kb per row which seems to be way too much. Unless it is. Perhaps `select *` is not what you want - try reducing only to columns you are actually using. If that doesn't work then perhaps you have to do the job in batches. Another issue is `DictCursor`. It probably doubles your memory usage since it turns tuples into dictionaries (it has to store column names within each dict). Use default cursor_factory (work with tuples). In case when column names are as big as values then you will reduce x2 memory usage, probably more.

Comment: Note that for example a boolean value `True` uses 28b (at least in Python3.3) while a string `my_column` 58 which is over twice as much. So you effectively triple memory usage with such boolean column when using dicts.

Comment: Yes, that did it! Each row has a couple hundred fields, and I was using 20 of them. Switched off DictCursor and only selected the fields I was using. Memory usage topped at 150mbs.

Comment: Great, I'll post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things worth noting

1) Don't use `select *`. There are two reasons for that: first, you load more data then you probably need. Second is that you have no control over the order of data (that will be important once we go to point 2))

2) Don't use `DictCursor`. It turns each row into a dict which eats **lots** of memory (since you effectively duplicate column names in each dict). Use default cursor_factory instead. Now in order to know the order of fields returned in tuples you have to specify that order in your `select` query.

That should take care of your problem. If it does not, then you have to do the job over smaller set of data.